# Google chrome not showing all markup code (ASP.NET MVC VS2017)

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, google-chrome

I am developing an ASP.NET MVC web application using visual studio community 2017.

I've been working for a few days with the html and everything work fine until yesterday that after adding some html code to the layout.cshtml file for some reason google chrome (neither IE) will show the elements.

The weird thing is that when I use the"show source code" option I can see that code but if I use the "developer tools" chrome won't show it.

The code is a regular navbar, with no css style yet, and I've rebuild several times the solution with no success.

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li>Option 1</li>
        <li>Option 2</li>
        <li>Option 3</li>
        <li>Option 4</li>
        <li>Option 5</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Any idea what is going wrong?

**EDIT: The whole .cshtml code**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es-es">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - website title</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="collapsed-menu-container">
            <div class="bar1"></div>
            <div class="bar2"></div>
            <div class="bar3"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="header-title">
            <span class="header-title-span">website title</span>
            <p class="header-subtitle">text</p>
        </div>
        <div class="shopping-bag">
            <object data='~/Assets/Icons/shopping-bag.svg' type='image/svg+xml' width='20' height='20' />
        </div>
    </header>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li>Option 1</li>
            <li>Option 2</li>
            <li>Option 3</li>
            <li>Option 4</li>
            <li>Option 5</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <div>
        @RenderBody()        
    </div>
    <footer>

    </footer>
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you post the full code from your view?

Comment: Hi @TroyCarlson, thanks for replying. I've added the content of the view.